# breaking a single C++ program into a multifile program with inheritance

Tags: c++

Consider the following code broken down into files according to the comments

```
// parent.h
#pragma once
class parent{
public:
    virtual ~parent() =0;
};
parent::~parent(){}


// child.h
#pragma once
#include "parent.h"
class child: public parent{
public:
    ~child();
};


// child.cpp
#include "child.h"
child::~child(){}


// main.cpp
#include "parent.h"
#include "child.h"
int main(){}
```

compiling the above code with `g++ main.cpp child.cpp` gives the following error:

```
duplicate symbol __ZN6parentD2Ev in:
    /var/folders/cr/zst9m2t112929f2wg4pkckjc0000gn/T/main-856b8b.o
    /var/folders/cr/zst9m2t112929f2wg4pkckjc0000gn/T/child-18a967.o
duplicate symbol __ZN6parentD1Ev in:
    /var/folders/cr/zst9m2t112929f2wg4pkckjc0000gn/T/main-856b8b.o
    /var/folders/cr/zst9m2t112929f2wg4pkckjc0000gn/T/child-18a967.o
duplicate symbol __ZN6parentD0Ev in:
    /var/folders/cr/zst9m2t112929f2wg4pkckjc0000gn/T/main-856b8b.o
    /var/folders/cr/zst9m2t112929f2wg4pkckjc0000gn/T/child-18a967.o
ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

however running this very similar program in a single file compiles and runs fine

```
class parent{
public:
    virtual ~parent() =0;
};
parent::~parent(){}

class child: public parent{
public:
    ~child();
};

child::~child(){}

int main(){}
```

why is this? how can I break the second single file program into a multifile program with out causing a compiling error, also what is the error and what causes it?

thanks

Comment: Looking at the error message, problem is in parent.h

Comment: Why is this in the header? `parent::~parent(){}`

Comment: where should I put parent::~parent(){}? also pragma once definely works, I've used it many times before

Comment: "breaking a single C++ program into a multifile program with inheritance" - using inheritance and breaking a program into multiple source files are two completely orthogonal things.

Comment: yes I agree they are orthogonal however the problem revolves around both breaking a program into multiple files and using inheritance, if you have a better name for the question please suggest it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the linker is saying, you have multiple definitions for `parent`'s destructor. In other words, this definition:

```
parent::~parent(){}
```

appears in both `main.cpp` and `child.cpp`.

To solve the issue, you can either:

- Move the definition into its own `parent.cpp` (like you did for `child.cpp`) so that there is only one in the whole program:

  ```
  parent::~parent(){}
  ```
- Or keep it in the header, but mark it as [inline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) so that multiple (identical) definitions are allowed:

  ```
  inline parent::~parent(){}
  ```

If the function was not pure virtual (`= 0`), you would also have the option of defining it directly when declaring it:

```
struct A
{
    virtual f() {};
}

// No need for f::f() {}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is the parent destructor being defined in the header outside the class definition.

Child.cpp and Main.cpp are two different translation units, both getting a copy of that destructor definition.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be this line in *parent.h*:

```
parent::~parent(){}
```

That defines a function, and it gets defined in every file which includes *parent.h*. Read the error message carefully,  and you should see it.

To fix, one way is to make the function definition in *parent.h* inline, for example like this:

```
inline parent::~parent(){}
```

If the method wasn't pure virtual, you could move the definition inside the class, and then it would be implicitly inline (but that won't work in this case). Then you could also move it to a *.cpp* file, so it goes to just one *.o* file and you avoid duplicate symbol.

Comment: It can't be moved inside the class, since it is pure virtual.

Comment: @Acorn Right, of course. Fixing the answer. Thanks.